# Is WFS:native mandatory to get OGC compliance?

Tags: wfs-t, ogc

I am a newbie to this domain. I am using WFS 1.1.0 and found out that is has a wfs: native operation. I wanted to know whether I can get OGC compliance without implementing WFS: native or is it mandatory to implement it to get OGC compliance.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be best if you would download and use the [test suites](http://cite.opengeospatial.org/teamengine/). That way you can test your program and see what else are mandatory at the same time. You can also check the [reference implementations](http://cite.opengeospatial.org/reference) at the site. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

My reading of WFS 1.1.0 says that it is required to be supported at the XML level (i.e. you need to include it in schema support) and you must implement the "safeToIgnore" directive (failing the request if the client sets that to false).

If you didn't implement these, then the client could reasonably send some special (vendor specific) command which was vital to the clients intent.

That said, you'd need to ask the OGC how they're currently interpreting it.